# AngularJS 1.6 - $onChanges executing twice

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angularjs-digest

I could be over-thinking this and that's why I'm here.  :)

Note: In the following example, the object "ctrl" is component's controller alias.  **var ctrl = this;**

Let's say we have a component that has two bindings where one is optional:

```
bindings: { 
   params: '<', 
   company: '<?' 
}
```

Sometimes the company is available, sometimes it's not.

The $onChanges looks something like:

```
ctrl.$onChanges = function(changes) {
    if (changes.params || changes.company) {
        console.log('executed');
    }
}
```

It seems that when both bindings are updated, $onChanges runs twice.  The first time, ctrl.company (the binding) is null in the component even though I did indeed update that binding with a value.  The second time, ctrl.company has it's value.

Now, I understand that the OR operation may not be correct.  I'm just a little uncertain about how $onChanges functions.

I'll update if my description of the problem is unclear.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 3):

[From Angular code:](https://code.angularjs.org/1.5.6/angular.js)

> `$onChanges(changesObj)` - Called whenever one-way (`<`) or interpolation (`@`) bindings are updated. The
>    *   `changesObj` is a hash whose keys are the names of the bound properties that have changed, and the values are an
>    *   object of the form `{ currentValue, previousValue, isFirstChange() }`. Use this hook to trigger updates within a
>    *   component such as cloning the bound value to prevent accidental mutation of the outer value.

So from my view you have 2 bind items: `params`and `company` that cause to `$onChanges` trigger twice.

If you want to write log once, I would write `&&`:

```
if (changes.params && changes.company) {
    console.log('executed');
 }
```